# NODE.JS with express website routing error

Tags: node.js, express

I am writing a website in node.js and express. At the current moment if i run the website the login controller is loaded every time and it just loads forever.

I don't want the login controller to be loaded when i load the page. I need to to be loaded when i click on my button login.

This is my Router.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/login/:username/:password', function(req, res) {
        var login = require('../controllers/login');
        login.userLogin
    });

    app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'Trace User Login'
        });
    });
}
```

This is my jade page

```
extends layout

block content
   div#login
      label#lblInfo Please enter your username and password.
      input#txtUsername.form-control.login(placeholder='Username', type='text')
      input#txtPassword.form-control.login(placeholder='Password', type='password')
      a#btnLogin.btn.btn-danger.btn-lg(href='#') Login


block endContent
      div.footer
            p#dev Developed by : 
              a.redtextheadingsmall(href="http://www.verishare.co.za/", target="_blank") VeriShare
            p Telephone:     +27 (18) 294 1000 Fax: +27 (18) 294 3880  Email: 
              a.redtextheadingsmall(href="mailto:tracesupport@vccb.co.za") tracesupport@vccb.co.za            
            p We recommend that you view this website with: MS IE 10+ or Google Chrome 20.0+ or  Mozilla 20.0+
            p#copy Copyright © 2014 .. All Rights Reserved.
```

How do i go about getting the login module to only load once i click on the login button. At the current moment the page is not even rendering as it is just stuck in loading my login Controller

```
console.log('Inside controller');

exports.userLogin = function(request, respond){

    var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
    var Request = require('tedious').Request;

    var config = {
        userName: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        server: 'localhost',
        options: {
            instanceName: 'instance',
            database: 'tempdb'
        }
    };

    var connection = new Connection(config);
    connection.on('connect', function(err) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            var userName = request.params.username;
            var password = request.params.password;
            loginRequest(userName,password);
    });
};


function loginRequest(Username,Password) {
    request = new Request("sp_WT_ValidateUser", function(err, rowCount) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(rowCount + ' rows');
        }
    });

    request.addParameter('UserName', TYPES.VarChar, Username);
    request.addParameter('Password', TYPES.VarChar, Password);
    request.addOutputParameter('InvalidPasswordCounter', TYPES.VarChar);

    request.on('row', function(columns) {
        columns.forEach(function(column) {
            console.dir(column);
        });
        console.log('');
    });
    connection.execSql(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to fix my problems

```
var router = require('express').Router();

var login = require('../controllers/login');
router.post('/login', login.userLogin);

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Trace User Login'
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```